# Odata service hosted on Apache CXF

Tags: cxf, jax-rs, odata

I am trying to evaluate on how to host an OData service in CXF. I am basically interested in getting the parse tree from $filter and use it to fetch data.

My service stack uses JPA, Hibernate, Spring and Oracle DB

Answer (score 1):

See also http://java.dzone.com/articles/beyond-jax-rs-spec-apache-cxf where a CXF OData extension is described
Cheers, Sergey

Answer (score 0):

The `$filter` expression is a query parameter, therefore it maps to a method argument that has been annotated with `@QueryParam` (it can be very useful to specify a default value too, so that if the filter isn't supplied the method is still used):

```java
@GET
@Path("{collection}")
@Produces("application/json")
public SomeResultType getCollection(
        @PathParam("collection") String collection,
        @QueryParam("$filter") @DefaultValue("") String filter) {
    // ... Do the filtered query here ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to tell you how to parse and evaluate the filter, just how to get CXF to map from the OData protocol into a sane method call. You will probably want other `@QueryParam`/`@DefaultValue` combos in there too; OData has quite a few optional query parameters.